# Fixed and decimal places of a positive number

Tags: r, decimal, fixed, digits

I want to write a function for counting the number of fixed digits and the number of decimal digits of each positive number. For whole numbers: for example, for number 459 I would like to see

```
fixed=3 and decimal=0
```

as the output of the function. 
For decimal numbers: for example, for number 12.657 I would like to see

```
fixed=2 and decimal=3
```

(because 12 has two digits and 657 has three digits). For numbers less than 1 I would like to see

```
0
```

as the fixed, for example for number 0.4056 I would like to see

```
fixed=0 and decimal=4
```

or for number 0.13 I would like to see

```
fixed=0 and decimal=2
```

I have a general idea as follows:

```
digits<-function(x){
  length(strsplit(as.character(x),split="")[[1]])
}
```

I want to extend my code as a new one to work as I explained above.

Comment: let's say if you have a vector `v1 <- c(12, 12.657, 12.1)` what would be the ouptut i.e. the print values are `v1#
[1] 12.000 12.657 12.100`

Comment: My input is not a vector. I have a number as the input. For your example: for 12 I would like to see fixed=2 and dcimal=0, for 12.657 I would like to see fixed=2 and decimal=3, and finally for 12.1 as input I would like to see fixed=2 and decimal=1 in the output .

Comment: Is it a numeric format or as string

Comment: With function as.character we can convert a number to a string then work with the string.

Comment: It's minor, but *"my input is not a vector"* might be short-sighted: make your function deal with single values and vectors of arbitrary length *up-front*, and this function will be significantly better performing and adaptable to more situations. (Using `sapply` all of the time can get tiresome when it should have been vectorized up-front.)

Comment: Assuming the inputted number has a finite number of digits, my answer below should work properly.  It check to make sure you entered a real number, and accounts for both negative numbers and numbers between -1 and 1. Best wishes!

Comment: A fundamental problem with this (as has been mentioned at least once) is that computers are imperfect when storing floating-point numbers. In order to come up with intuitive output, you're going to need to set up some *rules* in order to trim out the known anomalies you're going to see. For instance, when `format(0.3/0.1, digits=17)` shows you `2.999...96`, do you say *"five 9s followed by something should be rounded up"*? What about an output of `1.000...1`, is that *"five 0s followed by something should be rounded down"*? From here, the slippery slope can only steepen.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this can be done. We cannot assume that a simple numeric value is accurately represented in the computer. Most floating-point values certainly can't.

Enter 0.3 at the R console:

```
> 0.3
[1] 0.3
```

Looks alright, doesn't it? But now, let us do this:

```
> print(0.3, digits=22)
[1] 0.29999999999999999
```

In essence, if you convert a floating-point number to a string *you* define how precise you want it. The computer cannot  give you that precision because it stores all numbers in bits and, thus, never gives you absolute precision. Even if you see the number as 0.3 and you think it has 0 fixed digits and 1 decimal because of that, this is because R chose to print it that way, not because that is the number represented in the computer's memory.

The other answers prove that a function can handle *simple cases*. I must admit that I learned that R does an incredible job interpreting the numbers. But we have to use caution! *As soon as we start transforming numbers, such function cannot guarantuee meaningful results*.

Comment: I understand what you explained. But for your example which is 0.3 I would like to see fixed=0 and decimal=1 as output.

Comment: This code: 
digits<-function(x){
  length(strsplit(as.character(x),split="")[[1]])
}
works for whole numbers. I want to extend it for decimal numbers.

Comment: The difference is that whole (i.e. integer) numbers can be represented in the computer "as is". A decimal cannot.

Comment: I think for example for number 12.456 we can convert it to a string using as.character() function. It will be "12.456". Then we can divide the string into two parts considering dot (.), I mean "12" and "456" then find the digits (length) of each part.

Comment: @vahid What  you should know is that you cannot wholly store a decimal in a computer. It is just an approximation. Hence once in a while you will get incorrect results

Answer (score 1):

It seems you kind of stuck hoping that this can be done. Okay here is a crude way:

```
fun <- function(x){
  stopifnot(is.numeric(as.numeric(x)))
  s = nchar(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x),".",fixed = TRUE)))
  if(as.numeric(x) < 1) s[1] <- s[1]-1
  setNames(as.list(s),c("fixed","decimal"))
}

CORRECT:

fun(10.234)
$fixed
[1] 2

$decimal
[1] 3

fun(-10.234)
$fixed
[1] 2

$decimal
[1] 3

fun(0.2346)
$fixed
[1] 0

$decimal
[1] 4

> fun(-0.2346)
$fixed
[1] 0

$decimal
[1] 4

INCORRECT: Note that fixed + decimal <=15!!!

fun(-10000567.2346678901876)
$fixed
[1] 8

$decimal
[1] 7 ## This is incorrect
```

The correct value is:

```
fun("-10000567.2346678901876") # Note that the input x is a string
$fixed
[1] 8

$decimal
[1] 13
```

Comment: Thank you for your code and important case fixed+decimal<=15 that you said to us. Why does your code work correctly for fun("-10000567.2346678901876") but  not work for fun(-10000567.2346678901876)? @Onyambu

Comment: How can we fix your code to work correctly for numeric inputs like 10000567.2346678901876? @Onyambu

Comment: Your code does not work for -1<x<0. For example in your code, fun(-0.2346) gives fixed=1 as output, which is not correct. For fun(-0.2346) we would see fixed=0 as output. @Onyambu

Answer (score 0):

EDITED (based on comments):

The below function will work for numbers with 15 or less significant figures:

```
digits<-function(x){
  ## make sure x is a number, if not stop 
  tryCatch(
    {
      x/1
    },
    error=function(cond) {
      stop('x must be a number')
    }
  )
  ## use nchar() and strsplit() to determine number of digits before decimal point
  fixed<-nchar(strsplit(as.character(x),"\\.")[[1]][1])
  ## check if negative
  if(substr(strsplit(as.character(x),"\\.")[[1]][1],1,1)=="-"){fixed<-fixed-1}
  ## check if -1<x<1
  if(as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(x),"\\.")[[1]][1])==0){fixed<-fixed-1}
  ## use nchar() and strsplit() to determine number of digits after decimal point
  decimal<-nchar(strsplit(as.character(x),"\\.")[[1]][2])
  ## for integers, replace NA decimal result with 0
  if(is.na(nchar(strsplit(as.character(x),"\\.")[[1]][2]))){decimal<-0}
  ## return results
  print(paste0("fixed: ",fixed," and decimal: ", decimal))
}
```

If you want to count negative signs (`-`) as a digit you'll need to remove:

```
## check if negative
if(substr(strsplit(as.character(x),"\\.")[[1]][1],1,1)=="-"){fixed<-fixed-1}
```

Note:  The 15 or less significant figures restriction is based on 8 byte floating point representation.

The only way I've been able to overcome this is by using the below code.

```
digits<-function(x){
  tryCatch(
    {
      as.numeric(x)/1
    },
    error=function(cond) {
      stop('x must be a number')
    }
  )
  j <- 0
  num <- x
  fixed <- 0
  decimal <- 0
  for(i in 1:nchar(x)){
    if(substr(num, i, i) == "."){
      j <- 1
    } else if(j==0){
      fixed <- fixed + 1
    } else{
      decimal <- decimal + 1
    }
  }
  if(substr(x,1,1)=="-" & substr(as.numeric(x),2,2)==0){
    fixed<-fixed-2
  }else if(substr(x,1,1)=="-"){
    fixed<-fixed-1
  }else if(substr(as.numeric(x),1,1)==0){
    fixed<-fixed-1
  }else{}
  print(paste0("fixed: ",fixed," and decimal: ", decimal))
}
```

However, this code requires the number to be passed into the function as a character string in order to compute passed 15 significant figures, such as is shown below:

```
x<-"111111111111111111111111111111111111.22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222"
digits(x)
```

Which returns:

> [1] "fixed: 36 and decimal: 47"

This then limits this function's applications as it cannot be used in a `dplyr` pipe, and you will not receive accurate results for numbers that have been previously rounded.  For example, using the same number as above, but storing it as a number instead of character string yields the below results:

```
x<-111111111111111111111111111111111111.22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
digits(x)
```

> [1] "fixed: 1 and decimal: 18"

I hope this at least somewhat helps!

Comment: This function cannot work because it does not use the argument `x`.

Comment: When I use this with `1/3` I get  `fixed: 1 and decimal: 15`. But when I check with `print(1/3, digits=16)` and - obviously - I do not get `0.3333333333333330` but `0.3333333333333333` with 16 3s. What is the true result with `1/3`?

Comment: I do not want to check the function for fractions like 1/3 or 1/7. I need the function for floating numbers like 1.323, 0.3 or 12.34 I mean the numbers that have a specific number of decimals.

Comment: @vahid Then this should work for you.  Best wishes!

Comment: @JoshuaMire, thank you for your code. It works. But why when I test the function for different examples the output is in red. Of course, the output for examples are correct but I wonder why outputs are not in black (as normal output that I ever see), but in this case the output is in red (they are like warning output in R).

Comment: @vahid This is because I used the `message()` function.  You can change this to the `print()` function if you need to use the output as an object (or if you prefer the black output).  I assumed since you were looking for a phrase returned instead of a vector/list/data.frame that you would prefer the `message()` function.

Comment: @JoshuaMire, I understood. You have used message in the final line of your code. I think because of using message, outputs were in the red. I changed "message" to "print", now the outputs are in black (it's normal to me).

Comment: @vahid I think you figured this out on your own while I was responding.  See my previous response for more detail.  If this works for you please accept the answer so others can more easily find the solution (and because it helps me out!)

Comment: @JoshuaMire, I understood there is a problem in your code. When I use digits(67845905677.2456991266788) output values are fixed:11 and decimal:4. But as we know in this case decimal must be 13 and so decimal:4 is wrong. As Onyambu has said in the following fixed+decimal must be less than 15. How can we solve this problem to fix digits function to work correctly for cases that fixed+decimal>15 as well?

Comment: @vahid My apologies.  I've updated my answer with my best workaround, however it will not work it your numbers are already stored, as they will have already been rounded.  Sorry I couldn't provide more help.

Comment: @JoshuaMire, Thank you so much for your attention.